# Rewrite url for the final path using CDN

Tags: cloudflare, cdn, azure-cdn, akamai

We currently use Azure CDN and can use the Verizon premium if needed or another CDN if required so we are not limited by a particular product.

We have a need to do significant number of url rewrites. Like thousands. I am hoping there is a smarter way to do using regex but unsure that would work.

Essentially we have lots of urls in the form of:
**https://www.somehost.se/blabla/mobler-15075**

These should be rewritten to:
**https://www.somehost.se/blabla/mobler/**

That is, the string after the last dash should be removed and replaced by a slash.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what have u tried to achieve desired output in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach should be to inspect the request and update its URL if needed. This technique is commonly used to serve a particular default document regardless of the path requested. It can also be applied to other use cases, eg to handle URLs based on regexes.

Typically such logic is applied at the origin, after which the logic it distributed to many global locations. My [AWS Cloudfront blog post](https://authguidance.com/lambda-edge-spa-extensions/) describes the approach. You would need to find the equivalent technique in your CDN of choice. Eg Azure CDN seems to support [URL rewrite regex actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions#url-rewrite).

Comment: Do you have any example of a suitable regex, for example with AWS Cloudfront?